# How to find degree of each vertex in graph - RDD Transformation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)))
```

the edge (Rdd1) was created through.

I want to find the degree of the each vertex in graph.

I want to add reversed order to RDD1.
`(2,1) (3,1) (4,1 ) (3,2) (4,2) (4,3)` will be added so that
I can find the order through the number of values ​​for each key.

How to add `(y,x) to (x,y)` among the elements of rdd1?

Answer (score 1):

```
rdd1.map(s=>((s._2,s._1),s))

((2,1),(1,2))
((4,2),(2,4))
((3,2),(2,3))
((3,1),(1,3))
((4,3),(3,4))
((4,1),(1,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Spark and graphs, you could have a look at [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/graphx-programming-guide.html).

To find the degrees of the vertices in the graph, you can use

```scala
val edges = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((2,1),(3,1),(4,1 ),(3,2),(4,2) ,(4,3)))
      .map(t => (t._1.toLong,t._2.toLong)) //the ids of the vertices have to be Long
    
val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(edges, 0) //create a (possibly distributed) graph

val degrees = new GraphOps(graph).degrees //calculate the degrees of all vertices
degrees.foreach(println)
```

prints

```
//(vertex-id, degree)
(4,3)
(2,3)
(3,3)
(1,3)
```